# When does Next.js API code that is placed outside of functions run?

Tags: node.js, next.js

I've seen some *Next.js* code using a pattern where some initialisation happens in the API file (within *pages/api/*), but written outside of the actual request and response function. This initialisation can then be assumed to be done from inside the API function, however when I tried to use the same import in a different API file, it told me that initialisation was not done. When is the code outside of the function run and how can I make sure initialisation happens before all API calls?

Here is the example I have explained, with the API that runs initialisation:

```
// other imports
import supertokens from 'supertokens-node'

supertokens.init(backendConfig())

export default async function superTokens(req, res) {
  //
  // using functions that rely on initialisation without problems
  //
}
```

And the API which also needs the initialisation

```
// other imports
import UserRoles from "supertokens-node/recipe/userroles";

export default function handler(req, res) {
  //
  // error when using UserRoles, which says that the supertokens.init function was not run
  //
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NextJS functions are run in a serverless env. This means that each function / API call (potentially) spins up a new process, which means that any memory state of a previous function call does not hold through. Therefore, you need to initialise SuperTokens in each of your serverless functions explicitly.

It's important to note that unlike prod deployment (in vercel for example), in local development, NextJS API functions are not run in serverless env, so the memory state does hold through across multiple API calls.

You can also leverage the [middleware function provided by NextJS](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/middleware) to intialize supertokens and make sure that this middleware runs before all of your serverless functions. This way, you won't need to add an explicit `supertokens.init` call in all your files.